# Configure "Run As" menu in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build custom eclipse plugin. In the process I am trying to add custom LaunchConfigurationShourtcut, but there are some difficulties.
i.e. [image]

I want to add a third option named "My run configuration", but I dont know how.

I have used this reference:
[ref](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts` extension point to declare a shortcut that appears on the Run or Debug cascade menu.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592493/how-do-i-use-org-eclipse-debug-ui-launchshortcuts)